# Can I power up a router with a phone charger?

Tags: power-supply, usb

Today, the charger for the modem for my cable-internet connection went dead. With shops closed due to coronavirus, I thought I would cut the connector from it, connect the two cables inside it with a cut USB-A to microUSB cable (leaving the USB-A in place) and use a phone charger. And so I did. Alas, it was apparently not enough to power on the modem - the diods would light up but I would not get a connection. The sticker on the modem says it needs 12 V at 1 A. I also have a router (that I actually use to cover my flat with wifi signal) whose sticker says 12 V at 2 A and that also did not work. I have another older and slower router labeled 9 V at 0.6 A that could work with this cable but it is slow and could only hold connection to three devices at the time (and we have at least nine in the house). I used a charger that says it can output 5 V at 2 A, 7 V at 1.67 A, 5 V at 2 A and 12V at 1.25 A (presumably using a usb-C cable).

Now, would using a different cable change things? I could cut a USB-C to USB-A cable. Pre-USB-C cables are all the same, are they not?

Would using a different charger change things? If I understand it correctly, that needs a "smart" device on the other end to support higher power, right?

In the end, I got a second hand charger (and ventured out) rated at 1.2A at 5V. Interestingly enough, it can power up the router (12V at 2A) and not the modem (12V at 1A) - I guess that is because the router only uses that power when USB devices are attached to it (it has two USB ports). Is that hunch correct?

Comment: To use the AFC(Adaptive fast charge) settings (everything but 5V) on that charger, you need to find out how an AFC compatible device indicates desired voltage to the charger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A USB charger provides 5V, usually 100mA (To get more power, it has to negotiate with the phone). This is not enough for your router, by an order of magnitude.

Comment: I see. But it was enough to power up the slow old router. Is it really 100mA and not more?